# eShopOnContainer - Docker: Visual Studio give exception trying to load the mvc page

Tags: visual-studio, docker, model-view-controller

I have setup the environment to load the eShopOnContainer, it compiled and ran inside my docker. When going to the page http://localhost:5100, this exception appear..

```
    An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to process this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
Generated Code

The type 'RazorViewAttribute' exists in both 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' and 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor, Version=2.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'
+
[assembly:global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Compilation.RazorViewAttribute(@"/Views/Catalog/Index.cshtml", typeof(AspNetCore.Views_Catalog_Index))]
The type 'RazorPage<TModel>' exists in both 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' and 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor, Version=2.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'
+
    public class Views_Catalog_Index : global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage<Microsoft.eShopOnContainers.WebMVC.ViewModels.CatalogViewModels.IndexViewModel>
'Views_Catalog_Index.ExecuteAsync()': no suitable method found to override
+
        public async override global::System.Threading.Tasks.Task ExecuteAsync()
The type 'Views_Catalog_Index' already contains a definition for '__Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_TagHelpers_SelectTagHelper'
+
        private global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.SelectTagHelper __Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_TagHelpers_SelectTagHelper;
The type 'UrlResolutionTagHelper' exists in both 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' and 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor, Version=2.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'
+
        private global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.TagHelpers.UrlResolutionTagHelper __Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Razor_TagHelpers_UrlResolutionTagHelper;
The type 'FormTagHelper' exists in both 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' and 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers, Version=2.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'
+
        private global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.FormTagHelper __Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_TagHelpers_FormTagHelper;
The type 'RenderAtEndOfFormTagHelper' exists in both 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' and 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers, Version=2.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'
+
        private global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.RenderAtEndOfFormTagHelper __Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_TagHelpers_RenderAtEndOfFormTagHelper;
The type 'SelectTagHelper' exists in both 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' and 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers, Version=2.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/3268) this issue, in asp github page.

Answer (score 0):

> The type 'RazorViewAttribute' exists in both 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor, Version=2.1.0.0, [...]' and 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor, Version=2.1.1.0 [...]'

This error is essentially saying that you have .NET Core 2.1.1, but are running it in the context of 2.1.0. You downloaded 2.1, but it was technically 2.1.1. The application compiles as part of 2.1.0, but changes to a razor template while the application is running is, for some reason, trying to hook into the 2.1.1 version of the runtime, so it loses touch with reality and the only way to bring it back is to restart the app.

The fix for this is to bump your .NET Core version number from 2.1.0 to 2.1.1 in your csproj file, like this:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.1.0" />
```

should be:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.1.1" />
```

Then restart the application once more and you'll be fine to make changes to your razor templates while it's running again.

Answer (score 0):

The error for me was :

> The type 'RazorViewAttribute' exists in both
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor, Version=2.1.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' and 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor,
>   Version=2.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'

I updated Microsoft.AspNetCore.App to

> 2.1.4 Stable version

and it seems it is fixed now.

The point is that we should update Microsoft.AspNetCore.App to latest stable version.